# I want to design a realistic Anti-gravity tank, how do I go about this?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, physics, artificial-gravity, armoured-vehicles

In one of my stories, some guys form the 22nd century introduce a gravity or magnetic based hover tank. The problem is I am limited to real world Armour technology and KE and CE type weapons. the KE weapons can be either electromagnetic or balistic based. The problem is how do I go about designing it in a semi realistic way? I want to keep the tank somewhat grounded in reality, so how should I go about designing it?.

Comment: What is the altitude limit of the technology?  Massive changes in design depending on whether the tank can fly 0.1, 1, 10, 100 or 1000 m above the ground.

Comment: Also, what speed can they fly at?  A tank that can only fly at 50 km/hr will be designed very differently to one that can fly at 500 km/hr.

Comment: What is the nature of 22nd century society and war?  What you want on the tank depends on what kind of things it will be fighting.  Is it a 22nd century repeat of WW2 or Vietnam?  Is it space opera?  Is it shooting drone swarms, or spaceships, or normal infantry, or other tanks?

Comment: 100M is the altitude limit, with the top tpeed being 32 m/s or 115 Km/hr. the 22nd century wars are more like vietnam but with other tanks shooting back.

Comment: large kinetic energy bases weapon mounted on a hover platform will always be a bad idea, the third law of motion is unforgiving.

Comment: would a small to medium calibre ke weapons like a 20 to 57mm autocannon be viable or is that still too large for cannon type weapons on a hover platform? recoilless guns might remedy the larger calibre problems on a hover platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words "realistic" and "anti-gravity" do not combine with science as we know it, but this is a site for building fictional worlds, after all.

- The difference between a tank and an [assault gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assault_gun) is the lack of a turret. No turret makes the assault gun cheaper, and easier to armor, but also less able to aim at off-axis targets. If your gravitic drive is reasonably agile, you could go back to turret-less vehicles.
- Recoil will be a problem, but a fixed-direction gun helps with some of that. Firing decelerates the tank or even moves it backwards, so the driver has to "floor the pedal" when the gunner wants to fire.
- For that matter, does the gravitic drive provide *thrust* or just *lift*? Fiction goes either way. It could be that the gravitic drive just makes the vehicle float in the air, like a balloon or airship, and that it requires something else (jet engine? ducted fans?) for thrust.
- Some modern tank designs put the engine in front, to protect the crew compartment. Can your antigrav tank be built that way, or does it have to have thrusters in the rear?

Answer (score 3):

**They work with what they have got.**

[image: mark liberty tank]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanks_of_the_United_States#/media/File:Allied_Mark_VIII_(Liberty)_Tank.jpg)

Your 22 century guys are antigrav engineers.  They have no knowledge or skills about armor or weapons and especially not 1930s armor or weapons.  To demonstrate what they do know,  they bolt an antigrav unit onto a Model T and go zooming around in it, ultimately wrecking it.  The military is impressed but not entirely convinced.  They do not want to risk one of their nice tanks.  They let your engineers modify a tank left from WW1 with the antigrav engine.

All the weapons and armor are as they came on the tank.  That will save you having to make up anything except the antigrav unit.

I do like the idea of additional antigrav units mounted as crowd control.  The tank turns the side mounted units on and throws the crowd down the street.

Comment: I see, so somthing like a old mark tank or a Renault FT series vehicle would be given to them for modification.

Comment: Absolutely.  Plus upgrading old tech keeps the focus on your antigravity hijinks.

Answer (score 1):

The best use case for hover tanks would be armoured cavalry*. Without much in the way of friction your going to be very unstable when stationary & very fast. So your not going to want to stop because when you do your advantage becomes a disadvantage. This is similar to cavalry of old as the horse wasn't much of an advantage when not moving.

They would also fill this cavalry role well due to their ability to simply hover over things normal vehicles couldn't go over. Things like river crossings & mine clearing are already difficult & being under fire doesn't help. With a hover tank its possible to hover over a river to clear out enemies on the other side before bridging. Or to cross a minefield to deal with enemies on the other side before getting out dedicated mine clearing equipment that would be vulnerable in combat.

one of their biggest advantages & disadvantages would be plane like speeds close to the ground. While it makes them hard to hit & they could fit more armour than planes making the things that can hit them less effective. But this causes the issue that in areas where there are large amounts of obstacles like forests you would need a very skilled drivers to avoid getting a massive hole in the vehicle as the speed would make anything that cant be flown over very dangerous.

It terms of weaponry you need to go low recoil. [RAVEN Cannons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvYhkyRPLLY), missiles & mortars are going to your best bets for weaponry. RAVEN cannons are effectively fancy recoilless rifles that use computers to get more velocity [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvYhkyRPLLY) link explains more. Missiles have a lot of their movement energy gained in flight not pushing against the hover vehicle from Mortars are the weird ones out of these, because they aren't low recoil, they're good because the recoil is mostly down allowing whatever's making it hover take the force rather than making the vehicle go in a random direction.

*Just like any alternative propulsion method based these hover tanks aren't going to replace normal vehicles as tracks or wheels are still better for 90% of situations & cheaper.

(I'm going to make this answer to be better later)

Answer (score 1):

Realistic tanks are designed against specific targets, like the Abrams which was designed against the Russian Cold War era tanks. However, armored vehicles also get their mobility chosen based on their purpose. Tracks are used for very rough terrain and heavy loads, but are inefficient and maintenance-heavy compared to wheeled vehicles, which makes wheeled vehicles much more useful for patrol duties, not to mention how tracks can damage the roads they drive on.

Your antigrav units would simply create a new category of vehicle options just like wheels and tracks do. If they work over water then antigrav armored vehicles (AAV's) would make excellent amphibious vehicles for assaulting beaches and across rivers, especially if they can temporarily fly a few meters higher than the water which allows them to assault many more beachheads.

Their design would be very affected by what they are designed for and what the antigrav capabilities are. Can you fly without exposing the antigrav generators? Then you can armor them much more than wheels and tracks can. Can they fly up for a moment? They would be excellent as a type of ground-based attack helicopter. Are they able to withstand recoil or not would define the weapons they can carry. The weight per square meter of antigrav determines the size and weight of the tank, etc.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ionic plasma propulsion.

Simply put, it's possible to ionize the atmosphere using electrical fields, and then use magnetic fields to propel the resulting plasma in order to produce thrust. Several proposed "antigravity" devices actually work on this principle.

It's possible your "antigravity tanks" use these sort of [magnetohydrodynamic engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamic_drive), similar to the [Wingless Electromagnetic Air Vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingless_Electromagnetic_Air_Vehicle) developed at the University of Florida in the 2000s and 2010s.